# Expected identifier but got reserved keyword 'reference' Product public reference; ^-------^

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, error

hello guys I am a beginner.
I would like to make a function for create a contract.

I found a example on the internet  but gives me an error so I dont know what should I do.

Anyone can help me ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Product {
    Factory public factory;
    Product public reference;//**here's the error**
function Product(Product _reference, Factory _factory){
    reference = _reference;
    factory = _factory;
}

function haveFactoryCreateProductWithReferenceToThis() public {
    emit ProductCreated(factory.createNewProduct(this));
}

event ProductCreated(Product indexed product);
}

contract Factory{
    function createNewProduct(Product _reference) public returns (Product) {
        Product p = new Product(_reference, this);
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: The contract is written for a previous Solidity version. If you want to upgrade it for `^0.5.0`, please read the following: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html (especially Constructors and Syntax sections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Product {
    Factory public factory;
    Product public x;
constructor(Product _reference, Factory _factory) public{
    x = _reference;
    factory = _factory;
}

function haveFactoryCreateProductWithReferenceToThis() public {
    emit ProductCreated(factory.createNewProduct(this));
}

event ProductCreated(Product indexed product);
}

contract Factory{
    function createNewProduct(Product _reference) public returns (Product) {
        Product p = new Product(_reference, this);
        return p;
    }
}
```

hey I make a small change and it's  work now !